# Compress .tar.gz - Add file in different directory of package

Tags: c#, compression, sharpziplib

I have a situation where I have two different directories and files inside those directory as shown below. and Now when I create .Tar.Gz package, I want to change a file to be created in separate directory. But I could not find a possible solution using `SharpZipLib`:

**Physical Directory Structure:**

```
- Parent1
    |------ File1.txt
    |------ File2.txt
- Parent2
    |------ File3.txt
    |------ File4.txt
    |------ File5.txt
- Parent3
    |------ File6.txt
```

**Directory Structure in .Tar.Gz**  (This is how I want to create structure in .Tar.Gz File6.txt should be inside Parent2):

```
- Parent1
    |------ File1.txt
    |------ File2.txt
- Parent2
    |------ File3.txt
    |------ File4.txt
    |------ File5.txt
    |------ File6.txt
```